# JPA with DB2 - Pessimistic locking with timeout

Tags: hibernate, jpa, db2, timeout, pessimistic-locking

I do pessimistic locking on an entity with JPA. The db is DB2 v10.x, JPA 2.0 over Hibernate 4.x.

I don't want to wait until the lock is available (it is locked by a long-time running process, keeping the lock on the entity for several minutes). I would prefer it to fail early (saying "Somebody else is working here"), and let the user decide later if he'd like to retry or not. I'm using:

```
Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
properties.put("javax.persistence.lock.timeout", 0);
getEntityManager().lock(entity, LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE, properties);
```

But the timeout hint is not honored (NB: no matter how I configure it, at the Spring configuration level, at the JDBC connection level or whatever). Setting it to whatever you like never change anything.

I suspect this is because it is translated to the SQL :

```
select ID from FOOBAR where ID =? and VERSION =? **for read only with rs use and keep update locks**
```

.. and there is no "NOWAIT" clause anywhere.

Is it possible to make the timeout working as expected, maybe making JPA do a `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE NOWAIT`? And additionally, if somebody know why is it translated by JPA to that statement instead of a more common one?

Comment: and does DB2 support "NOWAIT" ? https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_i5_54/db2/rbafzmstintsel.htm

Comment: ok, I guess I got it... soooo... No solutions? How about the JDBC param "currentLockTimeout" ? It has no effect as well...